# dynamic content in fullcalendar cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

How can i display different contents in fullcalendar date field. Please look at the following fiddle.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1465/)

Here, I have displayed a span "60%" as a static data. I want to display a different contents in a field.

For example,

I want to display like 60%, 70%, 50%, 80%, 90%, 45%, 62% like this any static numbers in a cell randomly.

How can I do this. Please help me.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
 editable: true,
});
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").append("<span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>60%</span>");
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I have dynamic json datas. But I want to in static for POC. So in static I don't know.

Comment: Well, I'm sure fullcalendar has to have something to manage the data inside the cells but if you want just to fill those cells one by one, instead of using 'append' directly you could use jQuery 'each' function... Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/

Comment: @jolmos Thank you so much. This is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you, try this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1473/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    editable: true,
});
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function() {
        var nums = [40,50,60,70,80,90,30,40,10];
        $('<span class="appendedNo">' + 
               nums[~~(Math.random()*nums.length)] + 
          '</span>').appendTo($(this));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer works, but it's not the right way to manipulate fullcalendar's events. These changes will be lost on view change. You will either need to put this code into `viewRender:` and all methods that update events, or use fullcalendar's builtin update method:

```
event.title = event.title + "60%";
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```